# Jira Custom field not executing when loading i jira ssue v8.5.9

Tags: javascript, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

We a custom field which is a multi select text field and wiki rendered,

We have added an AJS code as html as below,

```
<script> 
AJS.$(document).ready(function() {

AJS.$("#rowForcustomfield_10503").css({"width":"130%"});

AJS.$('.confluenceTable').find('tr').each(function() {
var tds = AJS.$(this).find('th');
var len = tds.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { AJS.$(tds[i]).css('text-align', 'center'); AJS.$(tds[i]).css('color', 'white'); AJS.$(tds[i]).css('background-color', '#5F5F5F '); } 

});

window.alert("Hi");

var ths = AJS.$("table tbody tr").find("th");
var len = ths.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
AJS.$(ths[i]).css({"width":"1px","white-space":"nowrap"});
}

AJS.$('.confluenceTable').find('tr').each(function() {
AJS.$(this).css('background-color', '#F2F2F2 ');
AJS.$(this).css('background-color', '#F1F1F1 ');

var tds = AJS.$(this).find('td');
var len = tds.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
AJS.$(tds[i]).css('text-align', 'center');
AJS.$(tds[i]).css('color', 'black');
AJS.$(tds[i]).css({"width":"1px","white-space":"nowrap"});
} 
});
```

It was coming with wrapping and misaligned. Hence we ran it in console and it worked, the custom field came no wrapped and worked fine. We have added a window.alert("Hi") to test and it displayed when run in console and when we edited the custom field.

BUT not while loading page. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you really paste the whole script? It's missing last two rows:

```
});
</script>
```

Also, another problem might be different location from where the JS is loaded. Try to put the code not into the Custom Field's description but into Custom Field's description under the Field Configuration Scheme. See this [Atlassian Knowledge Base](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/changes-to-custom-field-descriptions-are-not-visible-on-the-create-issue-screen-in-jira-server-833986770.html).